# QFile: chop a file into parts

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7

I am making a Qt application (4.7). Is there a way to split a file easily with `QFile`  so that if I have a file `x`, I can split it equally into n parts `fileX1`, `fileX2`, ... `fileXn`?

Comment: Recently, I had the same issue. As I store only likewise entities I solved it implementing `QDataStream operator<<()` and `QDataStream operator>>()`  for them and created a wrapper around QFile to handle the slices (round robin).

Comment: yes.. i was successful with QDataStream::readRawData and QDataStream::writeRawData .. Quick question.. can this handle a 5tb file splitting?

Comment: I never tried to handle files of that size. It should work, if you read/write <2GiB chunks at once (as it is limited to int). BTW, What Filesystem do you use?

Comment: ah.. the application is mean't to be cross platform.. and i want it to handle splitting huge mysql dbase storage files.. that can sometimes be huge..

Comment: You can get into trouble when accessing older [filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) as their maximum filesize usually is smaller than 5TiB (e.g. ext2/3 can handle files up to 2TiB, reiser3.5 only 2GiB). So the portability is slightly limited by the sheer amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no in-build QFile method to split an existing file.

Depending on your use-case you can easily read the file into a QByteArray, split that into n parts and save those back to disc. (If you want an example of how to do that, just comment to this answer.)

Comment: thanks.. yea.. i have been fiddling with QDataStream::readRawData to read the file... to a *buffer then save it with QDataStream::writeRawData.. i was very suprised when readRawData automaically increments its self.. (doesn't need seeking) But question.. can this handle a 5TB file that needs slitting? havent tried this thou..

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an option to configure Qt, to build it with "large file support". Just Google for "qt large file support" (without the quotes), to see many references to this.

But I can't find any mention of this in the [the Qt 4.7 Installation guide](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/installation.html).

However, the option `-no-largefile` is mentioned in the page [Platform and Compiler Notes - X11](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/platform-notes-x11.html).